# How does Azure determine the directory on logon and where is this documented?

Tags: azure, entra-id

On logging on to Azure (for example when going to portal.azure.com), a simple email address is enough for Azure to determine which Entra directory should be looked into to determine the method of authentication - even when the email's domain isn't the same as that of an Entra directory.

This email address can be anything, after all, such as any custom email address on any domain used for a Micrsosoft account, or as far as I know even some third party federated identity provider that is registered in the directory.

Thus, there must be some global index maintained by Microsoft that maps email addresses to directories, because how else would the login process understand which directory to look into? However, I can't find anything about this anywhere.

There is also (sometimes, not sure exactly when) a "Sign-in options" button that allows to "Sign in to an organization" to specify exactly which directory to use - in case the default one isn't the one the user wants to log in to. I have successfully used the same email address in multiple directories as an experiment, but I find that I then need to use this feature to specify which directory to log on to.

I'm wondering how exactly the default directory for the login is chosen, where that is documented, and if there is a way to change the default at all.

This question is more curiosity-driven and there is no underlying problem I need to solve. I have just been unable to completely understand the login process for years now and this bugs me.